# How to fix 'AttributeError' on using PyInstaller on a project with Tensorflow and Keras?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pyinstaller, tf.keras

The `--onefile` exe PyInstaller outputs crashes upon startup. The error is:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras'
[11288] Failed to execute script main
```

Note that the `main.py` script works fine though and never had this problem.

I'm doing all of this with PyCharm in Windows 10.

These commands were used to create the `.spec` file and to build the executable file:

```
pyi-makespec --onefile --name app main.py

pyinstaller --clean app.spec
```

Upon checking the generated `warn-app.txt`, I've seen this line:

```
missing module named keras - imported by ai (top-level)
```

I got rid of it by adding the path of `tensorflow.keras` to the generated `.spec` file before running the second command.

The path was determined through use of the terminal and the `venv` of my project:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.keras.__file__)
```

Or:

```
from tensorflow import keras
print(keras.__file__)
```

Which both yield `<path to venv folder>\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\api\_v2\keras\__init__.py`

This were then added to the .spec file under `pathex` such that:

```
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['<path to project folder>', '<path to venv folder>\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\api\_v2\keras\__init__.py'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
```

Upon running `pyinstaller --clean app.spec` again, the missing module warning on the `warn-app.txt` was gone, but the generated `--onefile` still crashes the error.

The code which requires the `tensorflow.keras` module is as simple as this:

In `ai.py`:

```py
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.load_model(`./model.hf5`)
```

The basic requirements (imported by the project itself) of the project as displayed by `pip freeze`:

```
numpy==1.16.4
opencv-python==4.1.0.25
pandas==0.25.0
PyInstaller==3.5
tensorflow==2.0.0a0
```

The extended requirements (downloaded and installed too when installing the basic requirements):

```
absl-py==0.7.1
altgraph==0.16.1
astor==0.8.0
future==0.17.1
gast==0.2.2
google-pasta==0.1.7
grpcio==1.22.0
h5py==2.9.0
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
Markdown==3.1.1
numpy==1.17.0
opencv-python==4.1.0.25
pandas==0.25.0
pefile==2019.4.18
protobuf==3.9.0
PyInstaller==3.5
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.1
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
PyYAML==5.1.2
scipy==1.3.0
six==1.12.0
tb-nightly==1.14.0a20190301
tensorflow==2.0.0a0
termcolor==1.1.0
tf-estimator-nightly==1.14.0.dev2019030115
Werkzeug==0.15.5
```

The whole error:

```
D:\Shared\CMSC\190-2\readr>readr.exe
Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation
Limited tf.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from modules.model import models
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "d:\shared\cmsc\190-2\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "modules\model.py", line 4, in <module>
    models = load_models(n=num_models)
  File "modules\ai.py", line 28, in load_models
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(os.path.join('.', 'models', ('m' + str(i) + 'eF.h5')))
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras'
[11288] Failed to execute script main
```

I honestly thought getting rid of that missing module warning would get it fixed, but it's still here, and I don't know why.

Comment: Have you tried adding `hidden-import=tensorflow.keras` flag?

Comment: I tried it, but the `AttributeError` is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading to `tensorflow==1.14.0` fixed the error for me.

This is now the basic requirements of my program:

```
numpy==1.16.4
opencv-python==4.1.0.25
pandas==0.25.0
PyInstaller==3.5
tensorflow==1.14.0
```

In the `.spec` file of my program, I also added `['tensorflow.keras']` to `hiddenimports`.

Answer (score -1):

even though "which tensorboard" showed that tensorboard was already installed, "pip install tensorboard" fixed the following error: Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.